# modelsim wave is empty and msg displays "xxx"

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I am running a verilog file on Modelsim, however the wave area is empty and displays a "xxxxxx" message. I am very new to Verilog/Modelsim/Quartus in general, any help would be greatly appreciated!
code:

```
module lfsr_prng (input clk, 
                        rst, 
                        output reg[2:0] out); 
                        
reg [5:0] lfsr; 

  always @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
    if (rst) begin
      // Reset the LFSR on rising edge of reset
      lfsr <= 6'b000000;
    end 
     else begin
      // LFSR feedback logic
      lfsr[5:1] <= lfsr[4:0];
      lfsr[0]   <= lfsr[5] ^ lfsr[4] ^ 1'b1;

      // Assign output bits
      out[2] <= lfsr[2];
      out[1] <= lfsr[4];
      out[0] <= lfsr[0];
    end
  end

endmodule
```

[modelsim screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtp8b.png)

is it something with the output in my code that causes nothing to display on the wave area?

Answer (score -1):

You need to run the simulation. do `run -a` in the transcript window in modelsim